# Link to password reset sent via email

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

What is the best way to create a validation link that will be sent to the email, to perform password exchange? I already have all the sending logic working, however I need to add this link that will be redirected to a View (RedefinicaoSenha) to change the password.

Follow the shipping method.

```
public void EnviarEmail()
        {
            try
            {
                //From Address  
                string FromAddress = _config.GetValue<string>("From");
                string FromAdressTitle = "TesteEnvio";
                //To Address  
                string ToAddress = CliEmail;
                string ToAdressTitle = "Microsoft ASP.NET Core";
                string Subject = "Redefinição de senha";//Assunto,
                string BodyContent = "Prezado(a)  para redefinir sua senha, por favor clique no link abaixo.";

                //Smtp Server  
                string SmtpServer = _config.GetValue<string>("SmtpServer");
                //Smtp Port Number  
                int SmtpPortNumber = _config.GetValue<Int32>("Port");

                var mimeMessage = new MimeMessage();
                mimeMessage.From.Add(new MailboxAddress(FromAdressTitle, FromAddress));
                mimeMessage.To.Add(new MailboxAddress(ToAdressTitle, ToAddress));
                mimeMessage.Subject = Subject;
                mimeMessage.Body = new TextPart("plain")
                {
                    Text = BodyContent

                };

                using (var client = new SmtpClient())
                {
                    client.Connect(SmtpServer, SmtpPortNumber, false);   
                    client.Authenticate(_config.GetValue<string>("Usuario"), _config.GetValue<string>("Password"));
                    client.Send(mimeMessage);
                    client.Disconnect(true);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                throw ex;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Side note: Change `throw ex;` to `throw;`. This ensures your original stack trace is preserved, leaving it like it is now will make the exception much more difficult to debug later down the call stack.

Comment: @Igor or just remove the try/catch altogether if you're not going to do anything with the exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use ASP.NET Identity framework. It will handle reset password token generation for you.

Something like that:

```
var code = await UserManager.GeneratePasswordResetTokenAsync(userId);
var callbackUrl = Url.Action(
    "ResetPassword", 
    "Account", 
    new { UserId = userId, code = code }, protocol: Request.Url.Scheme);
```

You can find more info here:

[Account Confirmation and Password Recovery with ASP.NET Identity (C#)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/identity/overview/features-api/account-confirmation-and-password-recovery-with-aspnet-identity)